# How run java web strat application with hsql and glassfish?

Tags: java, glassfish, hsqldb, java-web-start

I have java program with main function, that packaged into jar archive. There is dao class with DataSource. An jdbc url to data file is expected an is passed as argument to main function. Everything works as standalone application, but how I must link jar file with database when they both in glassfish? For example, I put jnlp into glassfish docroot directory, and put HSQL database file with populated data too. Whta link I must pass tho that database? If I simple replace
    "C:\path"

with

```
"http://localhost:8080\path_inside_docroot_folder"
```

I get EOFException in java when it tryies to read a file.

Off topic:
Also it very strange, when I created hsql database I write something like this:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:C:\\path\db_file.dat
```

But actually in the path there is no exactly db_file.dat. There are several files, like:

```
db_sile.dat.tmp
db_sile.dat.lck
db_sile.dat.log
db_sile.dat.properties
db_sile.dat.scrip
```

Can anyone solve my problem? May files mentioned upper influence to the problem or it is pure glassfish deploy problem?

If something unclear ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you can not run HSQL inside as static resource glassfish. You can run HSQL server as [HTTP server](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N10148) or [as servlet](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N10168) if you deploy web application. The solution for my problem is to put JNDI file and java jar file as static resources in glassfish and run HSQL server in the same computer (where glassfish is running).